# do irregular multiplication of vector space hold while taking an additive inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have been doing some university work and have a question related to vector space

Question: Determine whether the set $V = {(x, 1) ∶ x \in \mathbb{R}}$ equipped with the operations $(x_1, 1) + (x_2, 1) = (x_1 + x_2, 1)$ and $c(x, 1) = (cx, 1)$ is a vector space or not?

Now when we take additive inverse of a vector let's say $v_1 = (x_1,1)$

Should it be like $-v_1$ as in scalar operation that will result in $-v_1 = (-x_1,-1)$
Or will it involve the irregular vector multiplication given above which will result is $-1(v_1) = (-x1,1)$?

If latter is the case, can someone explain why don't we use the given operation of multiplication while we will still use irregular addition and does that mean additive inverse in both cases will not satisfy?

Thank you!

Comment: The vector $-v$ is the vector such that $v + (-v) = 0$. But you still don't know what $0$ is. By definition the vector $0$ is that vector such that $w+0=w$ for all vectors $w$. Now only use your new addition definitions to find what 0 is supposed to be, and later on find out what $-v$ is.

Comment: The vector $(-x, -1)$ is *not an element of $V$*. The definition of additive inverse is that $\mathbf{x} + (-\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}$. In your space $\mathbf{0} = (0, 1)$. So you can prove that $-(x, 1) = (-x, 1)$ in this case.

Comment: Please take a look at this [MathJax Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and format your question using MathJax when you have the time.

Comment: @Kolija I did find that 0 vector was equal to (0,1) but I can't seem to know if -v will involve Vector multiplication or not?

Comment: @preferred_anon I m sorry I don't understand 
If vector (-x,-1) is not a part of V then it shouldn't make vector space right?
How Can I prove that? By using irregular multiplication?
And how does it relate to 0?

Comment: You use the operations defined for you. Both the vector addition and the scalar multiplication are "irregular". Check whether using them you find the vector space axioms satisfied.

Comment: @StefanOctavian an edit suggested the reference I completed the edit
Do I need to edit more? 
Sorry I am really new and I don't have much experience with this.

Comment: @EthanBolker I did exactly that but I don't know if they will apply while taking additive inverse?

Comment: Looks good, apart from some missing curly braces. You can format them with ```\{``` and ```\}``` because ```{``` are ```}``` are formatting characters in MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additive inverses cannot be of the form $(-x,-1)$, since the $-1$ part does not exist in your vector space. All elements of $V$ are of the form $(x,1)$, for some $x\in\mathbb R$. **We need to determine what the additive identity is before we can find additive inverses.** To be clear, the additive identity may not be what you expect (e.g. $(0,0)$).

So, what element in $V$ has the property that when you add it to $(x,1)$, you get back $(x,1)$. Well, $(0,1)$ of course! Since
$$(x,1)+(0,1)=(x+0,1)=(x,1).$$

So $(0,1)$ is the additive identity.

Now, what is the additive inverse of $(x,1)$? It must be $(-x,1)$, since

$$(x,1)+(-x,1)=(x-x,1)=(0,1).$$

Comment: So the additive identity cannot be (0,0) because of the condition of set V?

Comment: Correct. The additive identity must be $(0,1)$ because of the addition rules and the fact that any other value for the second entry would preclude it from being an element of the set.

Comment: @huzaifaimran Correct, $(0,0)$ certainly cannot be the additive identity, because $(0,0)$ is not an element of $V$.

Comment: Got it, means the additive identity will always be from the set, and thus natural numbers that don't include 0 will not have any additive identity!

Answer (score 1):

The second entry isn’t changed by addition or multiplication, so you can ignore it and see that the resulting structure acts like the real numbers. This means that it acts like a vector space in terms of addition and scalar multiplication.

As for subtraction, you can think of it in one of two ways:

Multiplication by $-1$: Given the multiplication rule provided, the second case is true.

Inverse of addition: $-x$ is defined by $x+(-x)=0$
The addition defined doesn’t affect the second entry so there’s no need to change it. This means that the negative of an element has nothing to do with the it. The number that negates the vector is the number that negates the first entry.

Therefore, $-(x,1)=(-x,1)$

Comment: Multiplication rule will apply when taking additive inverse right?